# Geometric interpretation for the binary expansion using gradient

Tags: contest-math

The following question is modified from the the [2021 Mathsbombe](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/mathsbombe/archive/2021/problem.php?index=1) competition (now closed):

> Beatrice lines up an infinitely large piece of squared graph paper
> with red lines going horizontally at 1cm intervals and blue lines
> going vertically at 1cm intervals. Beatrice then draws an infinitely
> long straight line, with gradient $21/31$ to the horizontal starting
> from the point with coordinates $(0.5,0.5)$. Every time Beatrice's line crosses a
> red (horizontal) line she writes down R. Every time her line crosses a
> blue (vertical) line she writes down B. This way she makes an infinite
> sequence starting
> BRBRBBRBR..
>
> The first part of the picture is drawn below.

[image: PIC]

It turns out that the binary expansion of the gradient of the line, $21/31$,is $0..101011010...$  Which is the same as the sequence of letters BRBRBBRBR...

Is the a way to understand this connection?

Comment: What is the coordinates of the starting point? Your copy-paste didn't provide it. $\quad$  Also, what happens if the line passes through a vertex (IE I'm assuming the starting coordinates are $ (0, 0) $)

Comment: Sorry it was (0.5,0.5) which avoids the problem you talk about.